# Is it possible to intercept and cache WebSocket messages in a Service Worker like all the examples do for normal HTTP requests?

Tags: javascript, websocket, service-worker

I know you can create WebSocket connections from within a Service Worker itself; my question is more whether or not you can use a WebSocket from your app as normal and have the Service Worker intercept / cache WebSocket requests just like it can do for normal HTTP fetch requests?

Here's an example of intercepting and caching a normal HTTP request from a Service Worker.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  // If a match isn't found in the cache, the response
  // will look like a connection error
  event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request));
});
```

How would I setup the Service Worker if all of my requests were via WebSockets?

Comment: I think you should try listening for message event ie. `self.addEventListener('message', function(e) { console.log(e); });`  Do you have working WebSockets example code you could paste?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's not possible for a service worker to intercept Web Socket traffic.

The service worker's `fetch` event is triggered only for controlled clients' HTTPS requests, and the `message` event is triggered only for `postMessage()` requests from clients.

While [there is an HTTP handshake](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/885#issuecomment-210726448) when initiating a Web Socket connection, that handshake does not trigger a `fetch` handler, and neither does the actual traffic sent once the connection has been established.

Comment: Is this still true 6 years later in 2022?

Answer (score 1):

I think one should use `fetch` for the first load of the page, so its data can be cached and returned by the service worker when you're offline.

So you initiate the websocket connection only if you're online. No need to cache data then.

And you fallback in saving message in cache in the app side when it fails to send via socket.