# Is it possible to push the variable socket in my service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

My problematic : When i enter in my website, i want initiate my instance socket. After this, i want to use this instance to do all my response and request to my server in all my different page with the same instance.
I heard serviceWork can do that. 
So how can i push a variable socket with Service Worker ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to use a websocket to communicate with your server, and have that websocket available in a Service Worker. That is (unfortunately, but for good reasons) not possible.

[Is it possible to intercept and cache WebSocket messages in a Service Worker like all the examples do for normal HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741185/is-it-possible-to-intercept-and-cache-websocket-messages-in-a-service-worker-lik)

Comment: My question is different from this thread. I don't want intercept the websocket messages. I don't want two instance (so two socket ID) in my server for one users. So when a user connect in my website, i want to pass this variable socket in all my page from my website.

Comment: If I use only React, it's easy to pass socket in all the project. but i use old tech (only html,js,php, no framework client or server) and new tech (react). So i have this problem and i have many pages. I try localStorage but no possible, so i wanted to try Service Worker