# Angular service-worker. Caching received data

Tags: angular, service-worker

I want to cache the received JSON web socket.
When I receive the data, I save it in the object and want to cache it.
I cannot find information about this anywhere.
How should I do it?

I tried specifying the url websocket, but there was no caching.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
     {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/app/app.component.ts",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
    "dataGroups": [{
      "name": "api-freshness",
      "urls": ["wss://blablabla.ru/ws/"],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "freshness",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "3d",
        "timeout": "5s"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/39602235/6851836

Comment: Can a service-worker cache internal structures? Can I cache an object (array, variable)?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you activated PWA functionality by issuing the command **ng add @angular/pwa** and that the content above is from the file ngsw-config.json which should be placed in your src-folder.

Try adding the wildcards to the value of urls in datagroups so it looks like this:

```
"urls": ["wss://blablabla.ru/ws/**"]
```